# To Get The Date difference

Tags: mysql

Hi iam having two columns

```
PR_PurchaseRequestHistory    

1)uid                        
2)POUID                       
3)PRUID                        
4)PRDUID                      
5)CreatedDtTm                  
6)ModifiedDtTM

PO_PurchaseOrderDetails
1)uid   
2)PRUid
3)RespondedDtTm   
4)ModifiedDtTm
5)CreatedDtTm
```

(unique PRUId) is assigned for every new request and the order is placed POUId for that PRUId.I need to get average date difference for the ID's generated for Particular months

I thinks this makes  issue clear
Please help me out. I have been struck in this issue for long time

Comment: Which database are you using?

Comment: Probably this question must be on SQL forum

Comment: What's wrong with `TIMEDIFF(var1, var2)`?

Comment: Iam supposed to get the sum for entire month of date avg taken for datediff( respondeddtTm to createdDttm) where they are in diffreent tables .

Comment: I think your question should be rephrased. I'm lost with all the POUID, PRUID, etc...

Comment: What is the link between your two tables ?

Comment: @sharan - plain text schema does not help, please update with full schema generated by `show create table $your_table`

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT AVG(HOUR(TIMEDIFF(PO_PurchaseOrderDetails.RespondedDtTm, PR_PurchaseRequestHistory.CreatedDtTm)))
FROM PR_PurchaseRequestHistory
INNER JOIN PO_PurchaseOrderDetails ON PR_PurchaseRequestHistory.PRUID = PO_PurchaseOrderDetails.PRUID
WHERE MONTH(PR_PurchaseRequestHistory.CreatedDtTm) = 3 -- March
AND YEAR(PR_PurchaseRequestHistory.CreatedDtTm) = 2011
```